# Make an exception for [auto-implemented-propert]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Is it possible to make an exception for [auto-implemented-propert](/questions/tagged/auto-implemented-propert) in term of max tag length, and add `y` to `propert`?

Comment: Good golly, is there really any need for such a tag?

Comment: Can't we just burn it? I mean, 9 questions, at least 3 incorrectly tagged...

Comment: @jadarnel27: Auto implemented properties in [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) and [VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) are a pretty popular topic

Comment: @UristMcBobby: I think this happen due its extreme ugliness so just a few people tags their questions by it.

Comment: Sure, but it seems like it would be sufficient to tag them with [properties] plus the language tag (and, as @UristMcBobby said, there are only 9 questions tagged this way).

Answer (score 8):

I'd rather merge that into [automatic-properties](/questions/tagged/automatic-properties) :) I'm also not entirely sure we need a synonym yet, given that the term is shared by CLR languages as well as Objective-C, which has its own similar take on automatic properties.

Just for kicks: this isn't the first tag to have a name that exceeds the character limit. Another somewhat well-known example is [nsfetchedresultscontrolle](/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultscontrolle) — which, at over 600 questions, is far more egregious...

Comment: Good catch! Agree.

Comment: Also `ssms` understandable by nobody instead of `sql-server-management-studio`